# slideDown() buggy behaviour

Tags: jquery

Example: `http://83.254.82.145:8080/android/`

Look at the menu at the bottom of the map. Try moving the cursor in from the bottom. Why does it show instantly? Same result with `animate()` and `slideDown()`.

```
$('#map_canvas, #map_menu').hover(function(e){

    $('#map_menu').stop(true, true).slideDown(200, 'easeOutCubic');

}, function(){

    $('#map_menu').stop(true, true).delay(500).slideUp(500, 'easeInCubic');

});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: maybe the map is messing it up? try putting it somewhere else on the page and see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 $('#mapbackground').hover(function(e){

    $('#map_menu').stop(true, true).slideDown(200, 'easeOutCubic');

  }, function(){

    $('#map_menu').stop(true, true).delay(500).slideUp(500, 'easeInCubic');

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I beleive your problem lies in this function:

```
$('#map_canvas, #map_menu').hover( ...
```

You are calling stop on the animation, so it is firing because you are hovering on the map_canvas, then immediately it is calling the hover on the map_menu because it is sliding up.